# OpenVPN with LDAP over TLS (ldaps)

Tags: ssl, openvpn, ldap

OpenVPN is using openvpn-auth-ldap plugin

I have an LDAP server (ApacheDS) running:

> Open/Clear - ldap://server.example.com:10399
>
> Encrypted - ldaps://server.example.com:10686

I can connect and authenticate without issue over clear text (unencrypted) but cannot seem to communicate with the server over TLS.

I connect to this server over TLS through various other systems (our code repo, jenkins, etc all authenticate over Encrypted ldaps protocol to it over port 10686 so I know the server is responding fine over TLS. It uses self-signed certs but that hasn't been an issue so far with other services connecting to it.

Based on the log files below, it seems the `TLSEnable` directive triggers the StartTLS function which I do not want. Regardless I've still experimented with using it...

Different configs I've tried:

**WORKS: (unencrypted)**

```
<LDAP>
        URL             ldap://server.example.com:10399
        Timeout         10
        TLSEnable       no
        FollowReferrals yes
</LDAP>
```

**DOES NOT WORK:**

```
<LDAP>
        URL             ldaps://server.example.com:10686
        Timeout         10
        TLSEnable       yes
        FollowReferrals yes
</LDAP>
```

Log:

```
Nov 28 18:05:47 openvpn1 ovpn-server[3282]: Unable to enable STARTTLS: Can't contact LDAP server
Nov 28 18:05:47 openvpn1 ovpn-server[3282]: LDAP connect failed.
Nov 28 18:05:47 openvpn1 ovpn-server[3282]: x.x.x.x:19939 PLUGIN_CALL: POST /etc/openvpn/openvpn-auth-ldap.so/PLUGIN_AUTH_USER_PASS_VERIFY status=1
Nov 28 18:05:47 openvpn1 ovpn-server[3282]: x.x.x.x:19939 PLUGIN_CALL: plugin function PLUGIN_AUTH_USER_PASS_VERIFY failed with status 1: /etc/openvpn/openvpn-auth-ldap.so
Nov 28 18:05:47 openvpn1 ovpn-server[3282]: x.x.x.x:19939 TLS Auth Error: Auth Username/Password verification failed for peer
Nov 28 18:05:47 openvpn1 ovpn-server[3282]: x.x.x.x:19939 SIGTERM[soft,auth-control-exit] received, client-instance exiting
```

**ALSO DOES NOT WORK:**

```
<LDAP>
        URL             ldaps://server.example.com:10686
        Timeout         10
        TLSEnable       no
        FollowReferrals yes
</LDAP>
```

Log:

```
Nov 28 18:17:42 openvpn1 ovpn-server[3412]: LDAP search failed: Can't contact LDAP server ((unknown error code))
Nov 28 18:17:42 openvpn1 ovpn-server[3412]: LDAP user "myuser" was not found.
Nov 28 18:17:42 openvpn1 ovpn-server[3412]: x.x.x.x:20248 PLUGIN_CALL: POST /etc/openvpn/openvpn-auth-ldap.so/PLUGIN_AUTH_USER_PASS_VERIFY status=1
Nov 28 18:17:42 openvpn1 ovpn-server[3412]: x.x.x.x:20248 PLUGIN_CALL: plugin function PLUGIN_AUTH_USER_PASS_VERIFY failed with status 1: /etc/openvpn/openvpn-auth-ldap.so
Nov 28 18:17:42 openvpn1 ovpn-server[3412]: x.x.x.x:20248 TLS Auth Error: Auth Username/Password verification failed for peer
```

**ALSO DOES NOT WORK:**

```
<LDAP>
        URL             ldap://server.example.com:10686
        Timeout         10
        TLSEnable       yes
        FollowReferrals yes
</LDAP>
```

Log:

```
Nov 28 18:02:47 openvpn1 ovpn-server[3232]: Unable to enable STARTTLS: Can't contact LDAP server
Nov 28 18:02:47 openvpn1 ovpn-server[3232]: LDAP connect failed.
Nov 28 18:02:47 openvpn1 ovpn-server[3232]: x.x.x.x:22910 PLUGIN_CALL: POST /etc/openvpn/openvpn-auth-ldap.so/PLUGIN_AUTH_USER_PASS_VERIFY status=1
Nov 28 18:02:47 openvpn1 ovpn-server[3232]: x.x.x.x:22910 PLUGIN_CALL: plugin function PLUGIN_AUTH_USER_PASS_VERIFY failed with status 1: /etc/openvpn/openvpn-auth-ldap.so
Nov 28 18:02:47 openvpn1 ovpn-server[3232]: x.x.x.x:22910 TLS Auth Error: Auth Username/Password verification failed for peer
Nov 28 18:02:48 openvpn1 ovpn-server[3232]: x.x.x.x:22910 Control Channel: TLSv1.2, cipher TLSv1/SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Nov 28 18:02:48 openvpn1 ovpn-server[3232]: x.x.x.x:22910 Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]108.47.9.178:22910
Nov 28 18:02:48 openvpn1 ovpn-server[3232]: x.x.x.x:22910 SIGTERM[soft,auth-control-exit] received, client-instance exiting
```

**ALSO DOES NOT WORK:**

```
<LDAP>
        URL             ldap://server.example.com:10686
        Timeout         10
        TLSEnable       no
        FollowReferrals yes
</LDAP>
```

Log:

```
Nov 28 18:21:07 openvpn1 ovpn-server[3462]: LDAP search failed: Can't contact LDAP server
Nov 28 18:21:07 openvpn1 ovpn-server[3462]: LDAP user "myuser" was not found.
Nov 28 18:21:07 openvpn1 ovpn-server[3462]: x.x.x.x:2946 PLUGIN_CALL: POST /etc/openvpn/openvpn-auth-ldap.so/PLUGIN_AUTH_USER_PASS_VERIFY status=1
Nov 28 18:21:07 openvpn1 ovpn-server[3462]: x.x.x.x:2946 PLUGIN_CALL: plugin function PLUGIN_AUTH_USER_PASS_VERIFY failed with status 1: /etc/openvpn/openvpn-auth-ldap.so
Nov 28 18:21:07 openvpn1 ovpn-server[3462]: x.x.x.x:2946 TLS Auth Error: Auth Username/Password verification failed for peer
```

Comment: isnt the port should be 10399 in the example with ldap:// and TLSEnable yes. 'TLSEnable yes' is supposed to enable STARTTLS, so you connect first on port 10399 and start TLS second.

Comment: Thanks. This is just LDAPS, it doesn't use STARTTLS. 
Due to this, I believe I should be using `ldaps://` and `TLSEnable=no` -- does that sound right? 
I'll attempt it as you mentioned regardless. 
I learned the difference between ldaps and startTLS through this config troubleshooting so it's a new topic for me.

Comment: you should try *TLSEnable=yes* and *ldap://:10399*

Comment: Appreciate the input. With that I get the same `Unable to enable STARTTLS: Connect error ((unknown error code))` I think the directive `TLSEnable` turns on `StartTLS` which my LDAP server doesn't use. Server has simple TLS on port `10686` which is how I have other services connected to it.

Comment: you should be able to enable STARTTLS on ApacheDS, actually it's more favorable, as ldaps is being deprecated, it's probably in advanced LDAP/LDAPS configuration.